# Black screen when "sleeping", only recoverable by connecting external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 19.04

Runing Ubuntu 19 on a Dell XPS 13' laptop.

I use two different external monitors on a daily basis (one at work, one at home). I also use the laptop without an external monitor on a daily basis.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 19, whenever running on battery without external monitor, the monitor goes to "sleep" after a few minutes of inactivity. The keyboard lights turn on if any key is pressed and I think the computer is fully on, but with a black screen. I have disabled the "real" sleep mode since that caused other issues.

The problem is that once the screen sleeps, there is no way to get the image back other than plugging in an external monitor. When I do so, the image comes back on both the laptop screen and the external monitor (as it should). Then after a few seconds I can unplug the monitor and keep working.

It's not an OS crash/freeze or hard hangup, but quite annoying anyway.
Any ideas why this happens and any ideas for a fix so that the screen doesn't go black in the first place?

Edit: In the power settings, I have "Put display to sleep when inactive: **Never**" but apparently this happes anyway.